# How to run a DEF if another DEF doesn't works and how to build it?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm building a program based on tkinter in Python, using Beautiful Soup from bs4 for Web Scraping from a private game server that show the winner nation from war (that wars happens every 4h per day). There is 2 nations and for each nation the website show the message "`Capella Ganhou!!`" and "`Procyon Ganhou!!`" (which means Capella Wins and Procyon Wins in Portuguese) and for each nation has an image to show. I made 2 defs for show the message frmo the website and a image for each nation wons. For some reason, always the first nation (Capella) is showing even if Procyon wons the war in the last war. I tried to find what I did wrong but I'm a beginner.

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import Image, display
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO


def capella_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[5].string)
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg, font=("Consolas", 25, "bold"), fg="pink").pack()
    except:
        return False


def procyon_tg():
    resultado_tg = StringVar()
    try:
        resultado_tg.set(soup.find_all("font")[4].string[3:])
        label_resultado_tg = Label(root, textvariable=resultado_tg, font=("Consolas", 25, "bold"), fg="blue").pack()
    except:
        return False


root = Tk()
root.title("Resultado TG Cabal Ghost")

ghost = "https://i.imgur.com/qSiXu68.png"
with urllib.request.urlopen(ghost) as iu: iraw_data = iu.read()
iim = Image.open(BytesIO(iraw_data))
iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(iim)
label_ghost = Label(root, image=iimage).pack()

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cabaleasy.com") as url: page = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

try:
    capella_tg()
    url_capella = "https://i.imgur.com/AHLqtt0.jpg"
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url_capella) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = Label(image=image).pack()

except procyon_tg():
    procyon_tg()
    url_procyon = "https://i.imgur.com/TQyCnfD.jpg"
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url_procyon) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = Label(image=image).pack()

cc = StringVar()
cc.set(soup.find_all("font")[2].string)
cc_label = Label(root, textvariable=cc).pack

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  You posted your entire program to illustrate a problem you should be able to show in 10-20 lines.  You will help yourself more if you insert strategic `print` statements to trace program flow and variable values.

Comment: It looks like you are misunderstanding what a `try`/`except` block does. It looks like you want an `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: You need to call `soup.find_all("font")` once and save the result to a list.  Then use the result list wherever you want.  Also the `except procyon_tg()` statement is invalid.  BTW, the whole `try/except` logic is wrong because the except block will never be called unless there is network issue.